# Decode a h265/HVEC bitstream to rawvideo(Y4M)

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg, video-processing, decoding, libx265

I encoded a raw video in Y4M format with the following command on Matlab

```
system(['ffmpeg -i ' videoNameIn, videoTypeIn, ' -s ' num2str(width),'x',num2str(height), ' -r ', num2str(frameRate), ' -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast',  videoNameOut, videoTypeOut]);
```

The output is in `.h265`. Now I want to decode it to the original format which means Y4M, how can I do that?

Comment: Decode using FFmpeg?

Comment: I know that, but how can I do that ?
I visited many web site, forums,  didn't find what I need or didn't know how to find it.

Comment: It wasn't a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.h265 out.y4m
```

If you need to pipe it,

```
ffmpeg -i in.h265 -f yuv4mpegpipe -
```

Comment: I used the second command 
`ffmpeg -i galleon_422_cif_out.h265 -f yuv4mpegpipe out.y4m`
The size of thz original video was : 73 MB.
The size of the output after encoding and decoding is : 869,8 MB.  
Is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, Y4M is uncompressed full raster.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with another question, could you explain more, the original and the final output are in the same format, so why there is a large difference in size ?                                                                                                            
73 <<<< 869,8

Comment: Show the full console output of the Y4M -> 265 and 265 -> Y4M encodes. Although I see that you rescaled the input when encoding to 265.

Comment: The console output is too long for a comment, do you want me to add it in the question ?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual method.  Use code formatting.

Comment: Sorry couldn't edit it, I just create a repo on github for this, so please take a look at this link [encoding output](https://github.com/sendja-3360/test/blob/master/console_output).

Comment: Your source is 352x288 and 265 output is 1600x900. So, you should expect a 1600*900/352/288 = 14.20x increase

Comment: Ok I understand? If I may another question, what did you mean by **pipe**.

Comment: ffmpeg can output to stdin of another app if it accepts such input. No file creation needed.

Comment: Didn't understand at 100%, but thanks for your answers and your time, I really appreciate it.